# Extracting a String from a List inside a Dictionary in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, text-parsing

I am new (one week old) to Python and would really appreciate some help. I am trying to extract a string (dates) from over 6,000 news articles. I am practicing with some made up texts that follows the same pattern as the news articles I want to work with:

> Lorem Ipsum Dolor
>
> Monday, 5/21/2017
>
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc fringilla arcu congue metus aliquam mollis.
>   Mauris nec maximus purus. Maecenas sit amet pretium tellus. Praesent sed rhoncus eo. Duis id commodo orci.
>   Quisque at dignissim lacus.

and:

> Lorem Ipsum Dolor
>
> Monday, 7/21/2017
>
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc fringilla arcu congue metus aliquam mollis.
>   Mauris nec maximus purus. Maecenas sit amet pretium tellus. Praesent sed rhoncus eo. Duis id commodo orci.
>   Quisque at dignissim lacus.

I know that these dates are in the same location for all .txt files. They fall between the line break (\n) after the title of each article and the next line break (\n).

So far I have managed to create a dictionary with the following code:

```
base_dir = 'C:/Users/Lorem/text'
output = {}
file_list = []

for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(base_dir):
for f in filenames:
    if 'txt' in str(f):
        e = os.path.join(str(dirpath), str(f))
        file_list.append(e)

for f in file_list:
    print f
    txtfile = open(f, 'r')
    output[f] = []
    for line in txtfile:
        if '\n' in line:
            output[f].append(line)
 tabs = []
 for tab in output:
     tabs.append(tab)
```

The output looks fine:

```
output
{'C:/Users/Lorem/text\\lorem.txt': ['Lorem Ipsum Dolor\n','Monday, 5/21/2017\n','\n','Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc fringilla arcu congue metus aliquam mollis.\n','Mauris nec maximus purus. Maecenas sit amet pretium tellus. Praesent sed rhoncus eo. Duis id commodo orci.\n'],'C:/Users/Lorem/text\\lorem2.txt': ['Lorem Ipsum Dolor\n','Monday, 7/21/2017\n','\n','Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc fringilla arcu congue metus aliquam mollis.\n','Mauris nec maximus purus. Maecenas sit amet pretium tellus. Praesent sed rhoncus eo. Duis id commodo orci.\n']}
```

At this point I attempted to use regex to extract the dates from the list in the dictionary:

```
result = []
for out in output.values():
    if re.search('Dolor\n,(.*)\n', out):
        result.append(out)
```

However, regex does not work on lists. How would I go about parsing out those dates from my list? Ideally I would like a dictionary or some data structure with text and dates so that I can move it to R were I am more comfortable working.

Thank you!

Comment: re.search() returns a value. You have to grab that value and then append it to your list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse using dictionary comprehension:

```
output = {'C:/Users/Lorem/text\\lorem.txt': ['Lorem Ipsum Dolor\n','Monday, 5/21/2017\n','\n','Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc fringilla arcu congue metus aliquam mollis.\n','Mauris nec maximus purus. Maecenas sit amet pretium tellus. Praesent sed rhoncus eo. Duis id commodo orci.\n'],'C:/Users/Lorem/text\\lorem2.txt': ['Lorem Ipsum Dolor\n','Monday, 7/21/2017\n','\n','Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc fringilla arcu congue metus aliquam mollis.\n','Mauris nec maximus purus. Maecenas sit amet pretium tellus. Praesent sed rhoncus eo. Duis id commodo orci.\n']}

dates = {a:b[1:3] for a, b in output.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'C:/Users/Lorem/text\\lorem2.txt': ['Monday, 7/21/2017\n', '\n'], 'C:/Users/Lorem/text\\lorem.txt': ['Monday, 5/21/2017\n', '\n']}
```